# Почему не получается подключиться к виртуальному хосту через другую ВМ?

Tags: linux, nginx, virtualbox

В первой ВМ linux:
По пути /var/www/hutsonr.com/html/ находится index.html с хтмл структурой

По пути /etc/nginx/sites-available находится hutsonr.com.conf с следующей структурой:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/hutsonr.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name hutonr.com www.hutsonr.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

По пути /etc/nginx/sites-enabled находится -s ссылка на hutsonr.com.conf

nginx -t ошибок не выдает

systemctl restart nginx - перезапустил nginx

По другой ВМ ubuntu я подключаюсь через браузер по адресу http://hutsonr.com , но выдает ошибку: Возникли ошибки найти сайт.

Обе ВМ подключены в VirtualBox по сетевому мосту

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Comment: Эээ, так обе виртуалки не у тебя на хосте, а где-то там?